# Cast generic structure to other structure

Tags: vb.net, generics, casting, type-conversion

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the problem I'm having. I want to apply some general rules to structures, and as the type of them differs, I want to use a generic function to do this. My problem is that to manipulate the structure via methods only available with parameters of a specified type, I can not find a way to do so without extensive casting. See, for example, what steps are needed to specify that a `DateTime` value should always be specified as UTC:

```
Public Shared Function Sanitize(Of T As Structure)(retValue As T?) As T?
    ' If value is DateTime it must be specified as UTC:
    If GetType(T) = GetType(DateTime) AndAlso retVal.HasValue Then
        ' To specify the value as UTC, it must first be casted into DateTime, as it is not know to the compiler that the type in fact IS
        ' DateTime, even if we just checked.
        Dim retValAsObj = CType(retVal, Object)
        Dim retValAsObjAsDateTime = CType(retValAsObj, DateTime)
        Dim retValWithSpecifiedKind = DateTime.SpecifyKind(retValAsObjAsDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc)
        retVal = CType(CType(retValWithSpecifiedKind, Object), T?)
    End If
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Am I missing something? Casting four times for such a simple task seems to complex for me to be the best / simplest solution.

Comment: Whenever you see yourself writing code like this then the lightbulb that should turn on is *this is not generic*.  With the somewhat inevitable outcome that such code just gets convoluted and painful.  Consider taking advantage of vb.net's decent support for dynamic typing, as long as you use Option Strict Off, getting ahead with `As Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods
With extension method you don't need to check type and cast it.
With extension method you will have own method for every type - simple to maintain
With extension method you will have "readable" syntax

```
<Extension>
Public Shared Function Sanitize(Date? nullable) AS Date?
{
    If nullable.HasValue = False Then Return nullable
    Return DateTime.SpecifyKind(nullable.Value, DateTimeKind.Utc)
}

<Extension>
Public Shared Function Sanitize(Integer? nullable) AS Integer?
{
    If nullable.HasValue = False Then Return nullable
    If nullable.Value < 0 Then Return 0
    Return nullable.Value
}
```

Somewhere in the code

```
Dim sanitizedDate As Date? = receivedDate.Sanitize()
Dim sanitizedAmount As Integer? = receivedAmount.Sanitize()
```

Extension methods have some downsides - for example you not able to "mock" them for unit testing, which force you to test "Sanitize" method every time it used (if you are using Test-First approach).